# Cron not executing shell script .. but working from commandline

Tags: php, bash, shell, cron, ubuntu-12.04

My os is Ubuntu 12.04

I am trying to execute a shell script from cron tab ..

that shell script works fine .. when i am  executing directly in command line .. like

```
sh out.sh
```

it works fine .. but when i am set cron for  this shell script its not working

my shell script : out.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox "http://localhost/acceptance/selenium-main/shell.php"
```

it will opens that shell.php webpage in firefox browser ...  its works fine when executing directly from CLI

..i an setting cron job like this

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then

```
23 13 * * * bash /usr/share/nginx/www/acceptance/selenium-main/out.sh
```

this was not working ..

i even tried

```
33 13 * * * /usr/share/nginx/www/acceptance/selenium-main/out.sh
```

this was also not working ..

even i tired executing from bin also : /usr/local/bin/out.sh

none of the methods are working

Please suggest how to fix this .. because crontab not executing shell scripts ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the behaviour of cron when configuring GUI applications. Try creating a wrapper script like,

**wrapper_script**:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xhost + 2>>/tmp/err.log
firefox "http://localhost/acceptance/selenium-main/shell.php" 2>>/tmp/err.log
```

Add cron entry as,

> 33 13 * * * bash /path/to/wrapper_script.sh

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .. i tried all the methods .. but nothing works for me .. even i tried in other system in my work station .. its not working for me ..

Comment: @user2728390 Did you execute wrapper script and check manually? If so, what is the error? Are you trying over SSH? if so, it has different procedure.

Comment: no SSH .. i am just using Ubuntu desktop ... 

Here is output when i manual enter in terminal :
    adi@zest-System-Product-Name:/usr/share/nginx/www/acceptance/selenium-main$ sh out.sh
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
 
.. but when executing manually ... script working well .. i dont know why cron is not working

Comment: As given in updated answer, redirect the error to /tmp/err.log and provide the log when run using cron. Also when opening the terminal on Ubuntu Desktop, what is the value of `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: You are looking like Programming scientist ... Really great .. its Now working for me .. Thank you so much ..

I have a doubt ..My shell script will execute a php file in firefox .. this php will generate a report .. it it possible to close this firefox window .. after this php file execution ...

Comment: @user2728390, Welcome. Please ask it as a separate question as it is different from this question.

Comment: @user2728390 Hi, I'm facing this same problem. Please, could you explain the solutionf working for you? Thanks

Comment: i tried VoidPointer solution which is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Try to use absolute path:

```
23 13 * * * /bin/bash /usr/share/nginx/www/acceptance/selenium-main/out.sh
```

Also try to run bash in login mode if something doesn't work right.

```
23 13 * * * /bin/bash -l /usr/share/nginx/www/acceptance/selenium-main/out.sh
```

That would try to fix other variables like PATH. If not, try to explicitly set it in your script, or just use absolute paths everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .. i tried all the methods .. but nothing works for me .. even i tried in other system in my work station .. its not working ...

Comment: i tried VoidPointer solution which is working for me now

Answer (score 0):

try the same solution konsolebox added to the firefox line in your shell script. maybe firefox is not in your path

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
php /path_to_localhost/acceptance/selenium-main/shell.php
```

If it is just producing a report and has no user interations, just run the script.  You do not need a browser to run php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference between running something in `cron` and from the command line is that your profile is run for your shell, so all the environment variables needed by your script are set correctly, but `cron` uses a naked "profile-less" shell.

Try using a script that sets all the environment variables it needs before executing the whatever the script does, so its "self contained".